# Ordering SQL databases

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I've started programming SQL in Python 3.7.6 and have started creating a 'cheat sheet' and it's all gone well until I try ordering it (the example I'm using here is ordering the database "database1", sheet name "test1"). I've read up online and have seen people using the code:

```
SELECT * FROM test1
ORDER BY fname
```

and this seems to work, but the issue I have is that it doesn't seem to be saving the database in this ordered form which is what I'm trying to achieve (the file does not change at all; the time modified doesn't change). I've seen other people attaching code so I'll put down the relevant segment at the end.

```
def order(fileName, sheet, attributes, condition, ascencion):
    connection = sqlite3.connect(fileName+".db")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    sql_command = """SELECT *
FROM """ + str(sheet) + "\n"
    sql_command += "ORDER BY "  + str(attributes[0][0])
    if ascencion.lower() == "increasing" or ascencion.lower() == "ascending":
        sql_command += " ASC;"
    elif ascencion.lower() == "decreasing" or ascension.lower() == "descending":
        sql_command += " DESC;"

    cursor.execute(sql_command)
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
```

Comment: Why *would* it change the database? You're just reading data.

Answer (score 0):

SQL table represent *unordered* sets.  You really should not think that there is any ordering, unless you specify that ordering.

So, just retrieve the data using the `order by` clause.

That said, SQLite is a file-based database, so it probably does preserved the ordering in the file regardless of the query.  However, because SQL does not in general behave this way, I would recommend that you not depend on it.

Instead, declare `fname` to be the primary key on the table or define a clustered index on the table using `fname`.  You will still need the `order by`, but there should be little to no overhead using these methods